# secondary listbox not show data

Tags: c#, mvvm

i've two listbox binded with properties of my viewmodel, the first listbox shows LstEmpresas and work fine, when I select a item, the property SelectedCompany sets fine, all ok.

In SelectedCompany's set of my viewmodel, I call a method than pupulate a secondary list (LtsEjercicios) and work fine too (LtsEjercicios populate perfectly depends that item i've selected in the first listbox).

The secondary listbox binds his ItemSource from LtsEjercicios object that, across viewmodel, is updated.

But the secondary listbox NOT SHOW any data, i'm crazy yet.

This viewModel code

```
public class frmEmpresasVM : ViewModelBase
{
    //propiedades
    EmpresasDataAccess empresasController = new EmpresasDataAccess();
    private ObservableCollection<EmpresasTable> lstEmpresas;
    private ObservableCollection<EmpresasEjerciciosTable> ltsEjercicios;

    public ObservableCollection<EmpresasTable> LstEmpresas
    {
        get
        {
            return lstEmpresas;
        }

        set
        {
            lstEmpresas = value; RaisePropertyChanged("LstEmpresas");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EmpresasEjerciciosTable> LtsEjercicios
    {
        get
        {
            return ltsEjercicios;
        }

        set
        {
            ltsEjercicios = value; RaisePropertyChanged("LtsEjercicios"); 
        }
    }


    //selected company in listbox
    private int selectedCompany;
    public int SelectedCompany
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedCompany;
        }

        set
        {
            selectedCompany = value;
            LtsEjercicios = empresasController.SelectExercicesById(selectedCompany.ToString());
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCompany");
        }
    }


    //main constructor, default values for lists
    public frmEmpresasVM()
    {
        LstEmpresas = empresasController.SelectOnlyNames();
        LtsEjercicios = empresasController.SelectExercicesById("0");

    }
```

and, XAML for the view

```
 <ListBox x:Name="companyList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="20,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450" ItemsSource="{Binding LstEmpresas, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCompany, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding LtsEjercicios, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="Nombre" SelectedValuePath="Id" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionChanged="companyList_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemBindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup/>
            </ListBox.ItemBindingGroup>
            <ListBox.DataContext>
                <InnovaCommerceHosteleryViewModels:frmEmpresasVM/>
            </ListBox.DataContext>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblEjercicio" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="475,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ejercicios" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="excercicesList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="205" Margin="475,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" ItemsSource="{Binding LtsEjercicios, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Ejercicio" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedIndex="0" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <ListBox.DataContext>
                <InnovaCommerceHosteleryViewModels:frmEmpresasVM/>
            </ListBox.DataContext>
```

Al Data provides from a MySQL Database from both tables (empresas y empresas_ejercicios).

My goal is, when user select a item in listbox1 (empresas) show exercices in listbox2 (empresas_ejercicios).

If exist other path to determine this operation, i'm all eyes!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only problem in your code, but what you're doing by setting

```
<ListBox.DataContext>
    <InnovaCommerceHosteleryViewModels:frmEmpresasVM/>
</ListBox.DataContext>
```

for both list boxes is creating a *separate instance* of the ViewModel for each list box. Now I guess if you make any changes in the first list box' ViewModel instance, these changes will not be reflected in the second list box because this one binds to a totally different ViewModel instance.

Instead, try globally binding the ViewModel to the whole window / page / user control / etc. (depending on whether you;re doing WPF, Windows Phone, etc.), and let the list boxes inherit it to ensure that only one ViewModel instance is involved:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <InnovaCommerceHosteleryViewModels:frmEmpresasVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you might as well instantiate the ViewModel once and store it as global resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <InnovaCommerceHosteleryViewModels:frmEmpresasVM x:Key="Viewmodel" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and in the listboxes' `DataContext` just reference this global resouce:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource Viewmodel}" ... />
```

Comment: Perfec!!!, i't is. Sorry but I've totally new in WPF and MVVM world. Thanks very much.